# DRV8830 motor controller -- drive is working but brake is not

Tags: dc-motor, i2c

[DRV8830 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8830.pdf) (control register info around page 11).

I have gotten this chip to run a motor with the following code:

```
void drive(int speed) {
  // Write to the Fault Register to reset it
  Wire.beginTransmission(MOTORA_WRITE);
  Wire.write(FAULT_addr);
  Wire.write(0x80);
  Wire.endTransmission(true);

  // Write to the Control Register
  Wire.beginTransmission(MOTORA_WRITE);
  Wire.write(CONTROL_addr);
  byte regValue;
  regValue = (byte)abs(speed); // Find the byte abs value of the input
  if (regValue > 63) regValue = 63;
  regValue = regValue << 2; // Left shift to make room for bits 1:0
  if (speed < 0) regValue |= 0x01; // Set bits 1:0 based on sign of input.
  else regValue |= 0x02;
  Wire.write(regValue);
  Wire.endTransmission(true);

  delay(100);
}
```

These are the addresses:

```
#define MOTORA_WRITE 0x64
#define CONTROL_addr 0x00
#define FAULT_addr 0x01
```

Here is my code to brake the motor:

```
void brake() {
  // Write to the Fault Register to reset it
  Wire.beginTransmission(MOTORA_WRITE);
  Wire.write(FAULT_addr);
  Wire.write(0x80);
  Wire.endTransmission(true);

  // Write to the Control Register
  Wire.beginTransmission(MOTORA_WRITE);
  Wire.write(CONTROL_addr);
  byte regValue=(byte)255;//0b11111111 -- I also tried 0b11 but that didn't work either
  Wire.write(regValue);
  Wire.endTransmission(true);

  delay(100);
}
```

The code for driving the motor works as expected.   When I call brake, however, it does not brake, even though bits 1 and 0 of the control register are set to 1.

[image]

[image]

I am using an ESP8266 for anyone interested.

Comment: Can you measure the OUT1 and OUT2 voltages if possible? In both when enabled to run and when brakes are applied.  Also, are nothing reverse and forward commands working fine?

Comment: Yeah should have done that before anything (it is actually working properly I just didn't realize it was resisting)... I'll leave this question up as a reference for the drv8830

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you measure the OUT1 and OUT2 voltages if possible? In both when enabled to run and when brakes are applied. Also, are nothing reverse and forward commands working fine?

Simple steps to make sure the commands are being transmitted or the bits are being interpreted properly.

Reverse and forward commands make sure that both bits are being addressed.

Brake should work.

If the motor is not stopping soon, I would do the following. If it is running in forward direction, I **enable it to run in reverse direction for short moment** and then apply brakes.. This brings motor into halt state faster.